# Morpheme trees, double lined head-branches

Tags: linguistics, trees

Does anyone know how to make a branch in a tree (tikz, qtree, forest...any would work) show up as a double line?  I have seen them used to indicate the headed-ness of a node in both syntax and in morphology, but i can't seem to figure out how to do it myself.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! Just add `edge+=double` to the child for the relevant branch in Forest. If you want more help, post an example showing what you've got. But it is perfectly straightforward in Forest or Ti*k*Z (same thing, of course). `qtree` would be different, but `tikz-qtree` should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [A
    [B]
    [C, edge+=double]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: double trouble]

Comment: Don't know why the image doesn't show up. It is there if you follow the link.